# Switching between "|" and "&&" symbols in a command based on input

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm using a bash script to concatenate the execution of a series of programs. Each of these programs produces an output and has two flags that can be set as `-iInputFile.txt` and `-oOutputFile.txt`, if no flag is set then standard input and output are automatically selected. Most of the time I simply concatenate my programs as

```
./Program1 | ./Program2 | ./Program3
```

but if I happen to need to save the data to a file, and then also access it from the next file I need to do

```
./Program1 | ./Program2 -oFile.txt && ./Program3 -iFile.txt
```

so my question is if there is a way to provide an input, for example `010`, and only convert the symbols between script 2 and 3 from `|` to `&&` while leaving everything else untouched. Hard-coding it would be impossible since I have up to 12 programs concatenated so it would have even 12! combinations. It's my first time asking so if anything is unclear from the question I'll edit to provide any information required, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Does piping to `tee` help? It takes stdin and outputs to both a file and stdout

Comment: You should know that `a|b` and `a -oFile && b -iFile` are different. After the first execution, there is no intermedia result stored in File. however the later one, the result of `a`  stored. you should understand your requirement. Also check the `tee` command, if it can help you.

Comment: SiegeX doesn't this just move the problem to switching between using and not using tee? Some of these files are pretty big and I don't need to save the content.

Comment: Kent yes, my question is because I don't need to save most of the time, only when I really need to I'd use the -o and -i flags

Comment: @User.cpp Alter your code so that even if `-o` is given, it still outputs to stdout (basically replicating `tee`).  You can then add a new flag to silence the stdout behavior, perhaps `-n` which is consistent with how `sed` works.  You can even add a check in your code to see if the arg to `-o` is an empty string and if so, ignore it.   That will let you script and 'hard code' the pipeline as `-o"$prog2Outfile"` and optionally set or unset $prog2Outfile

Comment: Unfortunately editing the programs is not an option, and the swich between file and standard output is handled by them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are scripting this, you can hard-code in `tee` between the pipeline and use bash's default value parameter expansion to essentially turn off the 'write to file feature'

```
./Program1 | tee ${outFile1:- /dev/null} | ./Program2 | tee ${outFile2:- /dev/null} | \
    ./Program3 | tee ${outFile3:- /dev/null}
```

Note that the last call to `tee` might be superfluous

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ unset outFile; echo foo | tee ${outFile:- /dev/null} | cat - && cat ./tmp
foo
cat: ./tmp: No such file or directory
$ outFile=./tmp; echo foo | tee ${outFile:- /dev/null} | cat - && cat ./tmp
foo
foo
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and is only 1 line! Thanks a lot!